# $\gcd(a_n ,a_{n+k})< \frac{a_k}2$ for a sequence such that $a_{k+2}=a_{k+1}+a_k$ and $\gcd(a_1,a_2)=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, inequality, recurrence-relations, gcd-and-lcm

How to solve:

Consider a sequence $(a_{k})_{k\geq 1}$ of natural number defined as follow: $a_1=a$ and $a_2=b$ with $a,b> 1$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$ for all $k$ >$0$, $a_{k+2}=a_{k+1}+a_k$. Prove that for all natural numbers $n$ and $k$, $\gcd(a_n ,a_{n+k})< \dfrac{a_k}{2}$.

I'm not comfortable with these problems how do I improve my skills to solve these (any books or topic........etc.)

Comment: This is not clear.  $\gcd$ of what?  Did you mean to write $\gcd(a_n,a_{n+k})<\frac {a_k}2$?  But this isn't true...for the ordinary Fibonacci numbers ($a=1,b=2$) we have $a_2=2,a_5=8$ and $\gcd(a_2,a_5)=2$ but $\frac {a_3}2=\frac 32=1.5$

Comment: Sorry, I missed the condition that $a,b>1$ so my counterexample doesn't hold.  So...is this what you meant to write?

Comment: @lulu ......most probably. I can't understand question myself, this appeared in my math contest.

Comment: Well...it's hard to guess.  And my reading is pure speculation...it's pretty far from what you wrote.  If you can get clarification from whomever set the contest, edit your post.  Otherwise...well, you might want to have a look at [this article](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/FibonacciGCD.shtml) which discusses properties of the gcd of Fibonacci numbers.  Should be possible to adapt these principles to your problem, whatever it turns out to be.

Comment: @lulu you can check problem: http://rmonorthzone.com/RMO_2016_Delhi_zone.pdf

Comment: Well, somewhat surprisingly that is what I guessed.  But it isn't true as stated...with $a_1=2$, $a_2=3$ we get $\gcd(a_n,a_{n+1})=1$ which is not less than $\frac {a_1}2$.  So, maybe they meant $≤$?  Maybe they meant $k>1$?  Again, it's asking a lot of your readers to make them guess.  More to the point, what have you tried?  As a starting exercise, prove that $\gcd(a_n,a_{n+1})=1$.  Now, what can you say about $k=2$?